# Remove last comma in StringBuilder SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, stringbuilder

I am creating a SQL Update Query using String Builder and if there is a comma at the end I need to remove it.

For example:

```
 Dim query As New StringBuilder
 query.AppendLine("Update Vendor")
 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(vendInfo.Name) Then
      query.AppendLine("Set VendorName= @VendorName, ")
 End If
 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(vendInfo.VendorType) Then
      query.AppendLine("VendorType= @VendorType, ")
 End If
```

The query errors on the last item since there will always be a comma. Once I am done going through all of my If statements I want to remove a comma from the end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a collection with each variable (sorry, c# here)

```
var list = new List<string>();
// add your vars
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendInfo.Name))
      list.Add("Set VendorName= @VendorName");
// and join them
var vars = string.Join(", ", list);
```

The secret is `String.Join`, which easily concats an enumerable of strings, placing a delimiter between each (but not at the end).

Answer (score 3):

Just decrease the Length property of the StringBuilder

```
query.Length -= 2
```

However, beware of your UPDATE query. The WHERE clause seems to be missing and a space is required between the TableName and the SET instruction.
Also another problem happens if you don't have a Vendinfo.Name. You exclude the code that insert the SET but this is required for the first field of your update

```
 Dim query As New StringBuilder
 query.AppendLine("Update Vendor SET ")
 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(vendInfo.Name) Then
      query.AppendLine("VendorName= @VendorName, ")
 End If
 If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(vendInfo.VendorType) Then
      query.AppendLine("VendorType= @VendorType, ")
 End If

 If query.Length > 18 Then
    ' 18 chars are fixed in UPDATE Vendor SET'
    query.Length -= 2
    ' add the WHERE clause'
    ......
 End If
```

Comment: ...just so long as the string format remains the same and the space isn't dropped... *[Yep - I know it's an old post!]*